# Most efficient way to sort text from an URL in Java

Tags: java, regex, url, sorting, dao

So I have a webpage that is ALL text, it contains thousands of lines of information like names, office numbers, etc. I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to make sense of this data. I can get the all the text without issue, but what would be the best way to sort it so I can add the information to the applicable class using my DAO.

For instance, I have dabbled with using Regex - but it's getting messy. Being relatively new with Java, I am wondering if there is a better way.

Right now, I have something like this (which is very loose, I am just trying different things until I get it to work to then implement it properly) :

```
private void read()
{
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputSteamReader(urlOne.openStream()));

  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

  while((result = reader.readLine()) != null)
  {
   //Regex here sorts things, once sorted it will add that to a List<foo>
  }
}
```

For me, the regex seems to be getting overly complicated, and I just have this feeling that I making more work for myself than is needed.

Comment: Is the page HTML or is it just text?

Comment: Just plain text, no HTML at all. It could just be treated as a plain .txt file...it just happens to be online.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: Time to go to the javadoc on that one. It seems like it could be helpful here, since all the data is more or less scattered. The trick is going to be knowing when to pick out the right text in the file.